# How do I check cache size in sqlite3

Tags: caching, sqlite, query-optimization

I am able to set the cache size using `PRAGMA cache_size`. But I am not able to view how much of cache size is used when I execute an insert or select.

I have also few other questions

1. Whether these caches are written to disk when we give end transaction ?
2. If caches are used for optimizing select statements, then when will the caches used by select statement will get deleted ?
3. Is there any way to view the amount of cache used my sqlite3 statements

Answer (score 0):

Such statistics can be queried with [sqlite3_db_status](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html).

1. Transactions [are durable](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html).
2. Cached data will be dropped when the connection is closed, or when other data needs to be cached.

Comment: Is there any equivalent java function for sqlite3_db_status ?